# How to use IS NOT NULL on a case when?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below SQL query in SSMS where I want to exclude `NULL` rows that show up in the 'intercompany budget' columns.

I've tried to search for answers and putting a `WHERE` clause for `'Intercompany Budget' IS NOT NULL`, like in the query below, but `NULL` rows still show up.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
SELECT 
    ONE.PROJECT_CODE AS 'Charter Number',
    TWO.Charter_sales_amount - SUM(ONE.HOME_VALUE) AS 'Gross Margin',
    SUM(CASE WHEN (ONE.COSTCENTRE_CODE = 'ACS 50% GM') THEN (ONE.HOME_VALUE) END) AS 'Intercompany Budget',
    (TWO.Charter_sales_amount - SUM(ONE.HOME_VALUE)) - SUM(CASE WHEN (ONE.COSTCENTRE_CODE = 'ACS 50% GM') THEN (ONE.HOME_VALUE) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Difference',
    ((TWO.Charter_sales_amount - SUM(ONE.HOME_VALUE)) - SUM(CASE WHEN (ONE.COSTCENTRE_CODE = 'ACS 50% GM') THEN (ONE.HOME_VALUE) ELSE 0 END)) / 2 AS 'Budget Adjustment Required'
FROM 
    dbo.AA_CST_CENTRE_TRANSACTION_SIMPLE_VIEW AS ONE 
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.CFMS_Charters_FlightsAndGrossMargin_IncICFLIGHT AS TWO ON ONE.PROJECT_CODE = TWO.Charter_Number
WHERE 
    ONE.CT_DEADLINE BETWEEN '2/1/2021' AND '5/15/2021'
    AND ONE.CT_TRANTYPE= 'MSC'
    AND 'Intercompany Budget' IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    ONE.PROJECT_CODE, TWO.Charter_sales_amount, TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin
HAVING 
    SUM(ONE.HOME_VALUE) <> 0
ORDER BY 
    one.PROJECT_CODE
```

Comment: `'Intercompany Budget' IS NOT NULL` can never be true, `'Intercompany Budget'` is a literal string and thus doesn't have the value `NULL`. This is actually one reason why using literal strings for aliases is a bad habit, as it causes misundestandings like this. `'Intercompany Budget'` doesn't refer to the column with the alias defined using `AS 'Intercompany Budget'`; it **literally** a literal string. It's only in aliasing that the syntax is (unfortunately) accepted.

Comment: @Larnu ah ok thank you.....do you know what I should do instead?

Comment: As an aside, get in the habit of using only `[Column]` (SQL Server style) or `"Column"` (ANSI style) for aliases; these can never be confused with string literals (`'value'`).

Comment: Either you use `[Intercompany Busget]` as alias or `IntercompanyBudget` (as Larnu suggested) or you modify the where clause to `WHERE sum(case when (ONE.COSTCENTRE_CODE= 'ACS 50% GM') then (ONE.HOME_VALUE) end) IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @Tyron78 you can't put aggregate functions in the `WHERE`.

Comment: @Larnu damn, you are right - however, the case itself should be sufficient in this case, since the SUM will only be null if the case is null

Comment: As another aside, don't use culturally ambiguous date formats like `2/1/2021` if you can help it. Assuming `CT_DEADLINE` is a `DATETIME`, a safe format is `20210201` (`yyyyMMdd`), which will parse correctly regardless of language settings. (`yyyy-MM-dd`, while more readable, is not safe for `DATETIME`, only for newer types like `DATE`. See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166771/what-date-time-literal-formats-are-language-and-dateformat-safe) for more info.)

Comment: Last but not least (too bad an answer with all improvements would make no sense as an answer :P) you probably want to make a habit of [avoiding `BETWEEN`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) for date/time calculations, since the results are not always intuitive.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you for your advise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'Intercompany Budget' IS NOT NULL` can never be true, `'Intercompany Budget'` is a literal string and thus doesn't have the value `NULL`. This is actually one reason why using literal strings for aliases is a bad habit, as it causes misunderstandings like this. `'Intercompany Budget'` doesn't refer to the column with the alias defined using `AS 'Intercompany Budget'`; it's **literally** a literal string. It's only in aliasing that the syntax is (unfortunately) accepted.

If you must use aliases that need to be delimit identified, then use the dialect's delimit identifier, brackets (`[]`) in T-SQL, or the ANSI delimit identifier, double quotes (`"`). Ideally, however, don't use aliases/names that require delimit identification at all. I tend to use PascalCase (as shown below).

As for filtering out the rows, one method would be to use a CTE:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ONE.PROJECT_CODE AS CharterNumber,
           TWO.Charter_sales_amount - SUM(ONE.HOME_VALUE) AS GrossMargin,
           SUM(CASE WHEN (ONE.COSTCENTRE_CODE = 'ACS 50% GM') THEN (ONE.HOME_VALUE) END) AS IntercompanyBudget,
           (TWO.Charter_sales_amount - SUM(ONE.HOME_VALUE))
           - SUM(CASE WHEN (ONE.COSTCENTRE_CODE = 'ACS 50% GM') THEN (ONE.HOME_VALUE)
                     ELSE 0
                 END) AS Difference,
           ((TWO.Charter_sales_amount - SUM(ONE.HOME_VALUE))
            - SUM(CASE WHEN (ONE.COSTCENTRE_CODE = 'ACS 50% GM') THEN (ONE.HOME_VALUE)
                      ELSE 0
                  END)) / 2 AS BudgetAdjustmentRequired
    FROM.dbo.AA_CST_CENTRE_TRANSACTION_SIMPLE_VIEW ONE
        LEFT JOIN.dbo.CFMS_Charters_FlightsAndGrossMargin_IncICFLIGHT TWO ON ONE.PROJECT_CODE = TWO.Charter_Number
    WHERE ONE.CT_DEADLINE BETWEEN '2/1/2021' AND '5/15/2021'
      AND ONE.CT_TRANTYPE = 'MSC'
    GROUP BY ONE.PROJECT_CODE,
             TWO.Charter_sales_amount,
             TWO.Charter_Gross_Margin
    HAVING SUM(ONE.HOME_VALUE) <> 0
    ORDER BY ONE.PROJECT_CODE)
SELECT CharterNumber,
       GrossMargin,
       IntercompanyBudget,
       Difference,
       BudgetAdjustmentRequired
FROM CTE
WHERE IntercompanyBudget IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! I will make sure to use aliases in the future